# If $\cos(\theta_n-\theta)\rightarrow 1$ then there exists $k_n$ s.t. $\theta_n+2k_n\pi\rightarrow \theta$

Tags: trigonometry, continuity

I was looking through this link: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Complex_Sequence_in_Polar_Form when I came across the statement.

I would presume that since $\cos$ is continuous, $\theta_n-\theta \rightarrow 2k\pi$ for some $k.$ But that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually about continuity of the inverse cosine function, not the continuity of cosine.  Let $\arccos$ denote the branch of inverse cosine taking values in $[0,\pi]$.  If $\cos(x_n)\to 1$, then by continuity of $\arccos$, $\arccos(\cos(x_n))\to\arccos(1)=0$.  Now $\arccos(\cos(x))$ always has the form $|x+2\pi k|$ for some integer $k$, so this means that there exist integers $k_n$ such that $|x_n+2\pi k_n|\to 0$.  If $x_n=\theta_n-\theta$, this means $|\theta_n+2\pi k_n-\theta|\to 0$ or $\theta_n+2\pi k_n\to \theta$ since $\theta$ does not change with $n$.

Comment: Hello, just to clarify are the $k_n$ unique? Im assuming  that for each n 
$k_n$ is s.t $2k_n\pi \leq x_n\leq 2(k_n+1)\pi$

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between $\theta_n-\theta - 2k\pi\to0$ and $\theta_n-\theta - 2k_n\pi\to0.$ The difference is that there is no need for $k_n$ to remain the same as $n$ changes.

Comment: Yes thats why i said it does not work. I cant seem to show that there exists a sequence of $k_n$